# Object field value when have property name as string

Tags: c#

I have an object of a model class.

I have to return the field of the object whose name is provided as a string parameter.

Is there a better way than writing the multiple `if` conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your existing code? You should be able to use reflection.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: Is there anything unclear in particular in this question that would require any code? I think it would help the OP to know what exactly they should highlight or demonstrate with code, so they can adequately weigh the M and E parts from MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "return the field" isn't 100% clear to me. Also if code is shown, answers can be in a specific context, which may be more helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *reflection* to retrieve the property value by its name.

First, obtain the [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) instace that represents your class. For example, use the `typeof` operator if the type is known at compile-time (including if it is a generic type parameter), or the `GetType()` method.

Then, you can use [`GetProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_) to retrieve a property with a given name. (Note that there are several overloads of that method that you may need in more complex cases, such as explicit interface implementations.)

The `GetProperty` method will return a [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.8) instance, by means of which you can retrieve the value.

For example:

```
object propertyValue = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty").GetValue(myObject);
```